# Unable to deploy smart conrtact using node js (not truffle)

Tags: web3js, tokens, contract-deployment, nodes

here is the code as explained in web3 doc(node:13887)

```
 web3.eth.estimateGas({data: '0x' + bytecode}).then(value=>{
 console.log('gasEstimate = ' + value);
 let MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,{
          from: publicKey,//user wallet 
          gasPrice: '10000000000000',
          gas: value
         });
 console.log('deploying contract...');
 MyContract.deploy().send(function(error, transactionHash){
  }).on('error', function(error){ })
    .on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt){
     console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address   })
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){  })
    .then(function(newContractInstance){
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
   });
});
```

here is error message

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 522
at createError (/home/project/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/home/project/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/project/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:13887) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13887) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to all this is working code

```
  web3.eth.estimateGas({data: '0x' + bytecode}).then(value=>{
  let MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,{
     from: publicKey,
     gasPrice: 1000000,
     gas: value
   });
  MyContract.deploy({
       data:  '0x' +   bytecode
       }).send({
               from: publicKey,
               gasPrice: 1000000,
               gas: value
      },function(error, transactionHash){})
        .on('error', function(error){ })
        .on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ })
        .on('receipt', function(receipt){})
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){  })
        .then(function(newContractInstance){ });
        });
```

Comment: I think you need to replace `MyContract.deploy()` with `(await MyContract.deploy())`... And of course, declare the entire function `async`.

Comment: @goodvibration the code is using the promises, look `then`

Comment: MyContract.deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to send the information that are required in order to deploy the contract. As [per doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id11) you have to provide the **bytecode** and the **arguments** of the constructor of your contract to the function `deploy`.

```
myContract.deploy({
    data: '0x12345...',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.send({
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891',
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}, function(error, transactionHash){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ ... })
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
   console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })
.then(function(newContractInstance){
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
});
```

Comment: I do have that part here 
 let MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,{
                                            from: publicKey,
                                            gasPrice: value,
                                            gas: '10000000000000'
                                        });

Comment: I can't see any bytecode there. To deploy the contract in the blockchain you need to send the bytecode. You're just initializing an object with the abi interface

Answer (score 0):

Status code 522 is HTTP connection timeout. Check if you have [set the provider and created web3 instance](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#web3) correctly. Check on your internet status as well.

Comment: I do have proper internet as blockchain is syncing and web3 instance as I am sending ether to the creator  so it will have ether for contract gas

Comment: @goodvibration - that is the example from web3 docs

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

Comment: You are right. I was confused on web3 interface at the moment.

Comment: Think @mirg is right

Comment: node v 8.11.2
provider rinkeby testneton our server

Comment: I mean ethereum network node like geth or parity, not NodeJS.

Comment: geth VERSION:
   1.8.4-unstable-a095b84e

Comment: If @mirg's solution does not work, I suggest to try upgrading your geth to the latest stable.

Comment: Not sure why to specify all thse details if there are already in new web3.eth.Contract(here)

Comment: ABI you pass into contract is different than the bytecode, the actual thing gets distributed to the network is the bycode that you've compiled. ABI is just an interface for interacting with this bycode.

Comment: where exactly I need to have abi ?
myContract.deploy({
    data: '0x12345...',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
as a value for data -key ?

Comment: You already did, `let MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, ...`. What you need to do is what exactly mirg said, just try to pass the data like contract.deploy({data: your_bytecode}), if you have constructor arguments then pass arguments.